# cmake execute process before anything else

Tags: cmake

I've a problem with CMake executing a process before doing anything else.

The following code snippet shows the situation:

```
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated")
  file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated")
  execute_process(
    # This tool generates library sources, which are not known before
    COMMAND "source_file_generator_command"
    # This tool iterates over the generated source tree and creates
    # a proper CMakeLists.txt in the 'generated' directory from the
    # source files found there
    COMMAND "cmake_lists_generator_command"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated"
  )
endif()

# At this point the generated subdirectory (with the also
# generated CMakeLists.txt file) shall be included
add_subdirectory(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated_build"
)
# But the 'add_subdirectory' statement fails due to non-existing
# CMakeLists.txt in the 'generated' source directory at this point
```

The problem is, as commented above, that the CMakeLists.txt file in the subdirectory which should be added is generated on the fly by a special script (the generated sources are not known before) during the first CMake run. Literally, I need CMake to wait until all the statements within the if/else block are executed and process the add_subdirectory statement not until everything is done (the CMakeLists.txt is generated). Is there an adequate solution for such a use case?

Thanks for your help,

Felix

Comment: `execute_process` should work before anything else. Note, that *several* `COMMAND`s given to it are executed **in pipe**, not sequencially. If you want true sequential execution, you need to use one `COMMAND` option per `execute_process` call.

Comment: Tsyvarev, thanks a lot. I splitted the command chain into two `execute_process` sections, now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

When several `COMMAND`s for `execute_process` are used, they are executed **in pipe**. From the [description](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) of this CMake command:

> Runs the given sequence of one or more commands with the standard output of each process **piped** to the standard input of the next.

If you want true **sequential** execution of the commands, you need to use **one call to `execute_process` per COMMAND**:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND "source_file_generator_command"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated"
)
execute_process(
    COMMAND "cmake_lists_generator_command"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated"
)
```